# Battery Monitoring updates at uneven intervals

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidevice, batterylevel

I am monitoring for battery events `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification` and `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification`. I am looking specifically for **20%** and **10%**, however, I am seeing these events fire off at 23%, 13% which they should be hitting at **0.05** intervals or every **5%**.

### Question

Does anyone else experience this, or is there a better way to ensure the levels are more accurate?

### Example

```
-(void)startMonitoringForBatteryChanges
{
    // Enable monitoring of battery status
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

    // Request to be notified when battery charge or state changes
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkBatteryStatus) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkBatteryStatus) name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)checkBatteryStatus
{
    float warningLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel] * 100;

    if ( warningLevel == 20.0 ) // 20%
    {
        NSLog(@"20% Warning.");
    }

    if ( warningLevel == 10.0 ) // 10%
    {
        NSLog(@"10% Warning.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement a timer and query the battery level manually (enabling batteryMonitoring before and disabling after reading the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]`). Note that it can still (just tested) happen that the reported level is not the same as level indicated on status bar.

Comment: Not optimal as thats the point of `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` and the other, to notify when there are changes.

Comment: You're definetly right. But i think it's the only way to get more frequent updates thus resolution that you're after. By the way: did you check what the status bar indicator says when you get 13% and 23% ... updates?

Comment: Yes, the issue is when the Console prints the NSLogs from the example above, the statusbar says 23% / 13% respectively.

Comment: I see - this discrepancy is a known issue. Similar problem in this (old) blog: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/device/display-battery-state-and-level-of-charge.html