# iOS Battery alert detection

Tags: ios, alert, detection, battery

I want to detect exactly when the low battery alerts come up on iPhone. They seem to come up around the 20% and 10% battery level amounts.

I CANNOT use ApplicationWillResignActive/DidEnterBackground, because I need to be able to distinguish these low battery alerts from other things that could cause ApplicationWillResignActive/DidEnterBackground to be called. This is a requirement of the program.

I CANNOT use UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification, because even though these are -supposed- to occur at every 5% change... it seems that in practice they are sometimes several percents off from the battery reading at the time, and therefore do not occur when the low battery alerts occur. See here ([Battery Monitoring updates at uneven intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926528/battery-monitoring-updates-at-uneven-intervals)).

Is there any way to uniquely detect these low battery alerts exactly when they occur and handle them separately from other application state changes?

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the battery level property from UIDevice. if the battery level is less than 5% show an alert for example. You could pool periodically for the battery level in your app delegate for example.

```
 UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice]; 
 [myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES]; 
 float batteryLevel = [myDevice batteryLevel];
```

And explanation from docs:

```
 batteryLevel
 The battery charge level for the device.

 @property (nonatomic, readonly) float batteryLevel  

 Discussion
 Battery level ranges from 0.0 (fully discharged) to 1.0 (100% charged). Before accessing this property, ensure that battery monitoring is enabled.

 If battery monitoring is not enabled, battery state is UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown and the value of this property is –1.0.

 Availability
 Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
 See Also
    @property batteryState
    @property batteryMonitoringEnabled
 Declared In
 UIDevice.h
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems a bit expensive, but we will try it out.  Any other advice?

Comment: Use the NSNotification to get within ~30% battery mark. Then turn on the polling to maximise efficiency.